# Increased backup file size when restoring SQL Server back up file to AWS RDS instance

Tags: sql-server, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds

I am experiencing this behaviour when I am trying to restore a sql server backup file to rds instance in aws. Backup file size is 4.6GB. When I restore this file to RDS instance, it works fine. But when I try to backup this rds instance, backup file generated is aroung 25GB.

I am not sure why file size is that much bigger than the original back up file size from SQL Server.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume backups are not [compressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/configure-backup-compression-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), that is why you get different size:

```
exec rdsadmin.dbo.rds_show_configuration;

-- enabling
EXEC rdsadmin.dbo.rds_set_configuration 'S3 backup compression', 'true';
```

Comment: This option is only available for Standard and Enterprise. Is there any way, I can manage cost and keep it down as this database is used for automated backups of production database.